# call a function inside struct but struct inside a void*

Tags: c

Can I first allocate a struct (with a function inside) to a void* and trigger the function inside them.

```
struct func {
    void (*fp)(); // this is a function
};

struct thread{
    void *stack; // I'm gonna use this to store 'struct func' above
};

void assign(struct thread *t,void *f()){
    struct func *task = (struct func *)malloc(sizeof(struct func));
    task->fp = f;
    t->stack = task;
    
    // question: now I want to call the function inside func and deeper inside void*
    // I mean: trigger the function fp()
    t->stack->fp(); // error here

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `stack` member has type `void *` and therefore can't be dereferenced as is.

You would first need to cast it to the proper pointer type (or assign to a pointer of that type) before dereferencing.

```
((struct func *)t->stack)->fp();
// or
struct func *f = t->stack;
f->fp();
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is avoided completely, if you use "correct<sup>TM</sup>" data types:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

struct func {
    void (*fp)();
};

struct thread {
    struct func *stack;
};

void assign(struct thread *t, void (*f)()) {
    struct func *task = malloc(sizeof *task);
    task->fp = f;
    t->stack = task;
}

void call(const struct thread *t) {
    t->stack->fp();
}

/* --- usage example --- */

#include <stdio.h>

void f(void) {
    puts("f() called.");
}

int main(void) {
    struct thread t;
    assign(&t, f);
    call(&t);
}
```

Notes:

- There is no need to cast the result of `malloc()`, it is actually a code smell.
- Using the target as argument to the operator `sizeof` avoids typos if you change the data type.
- The data type of argument `f` was not the function pointer. You need the set of parentheses.
- Declaring no parameters allows the referenced function to take any parameters. If you want "no parameters", use `void` like in `void (*fp)(void)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct func {
    void (*fp)(); // this is a function
};
```

This is not a function. It is just a pointer to a function that returns `void`. If you want it to use no arguments declare it `(fp)(void)`

> *"Can I first allocate a struct (with a function inside) to a void* and trigger the function inside them?"*

Yes, you can.

### Example

The following is a common way to write this type of thing.

It is common to `typedef` these things for easy reference, as in

```
typedef void(Function)(void);

typedef struct
{
    void* fp;
    // other stuff
} Container;

Container* so_create_c(Function*);
Container* so_delete_c(Container*);
int        assign_f_to_c(Function*, Container*);

typedef struct
{
    Container* stack;
    // other stuff
} Thread;

void f1(void);
void f2(void);
```

In `Container` `fp` could be just `Function*`, but you asked for `void*` in the question. Using `void*` means that at the moment of the call `fp` should be cast to `Function*`, as in

```
        ((Function*)t1.stack->fp)();
```

See example code below.

#### output

```
no function in Thread!
hi from f1
***** hi from f2! *****
***** hi from f2! *****
```

#### code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void(Function)(void);

typedef struct
{
    void* fp;
    // other stuff
} Container;

Container* so_create_c(Function*);
Container* so_delete_c(Container*);
int        assign_f_to_c(Function*, Container*);

typedef struct
{
    Container* stack;
    // other stuff
} Thread;

void f1(void);
void f2(void);

int main(void)
{
    Container* c1 = so_create_c(NULL);
    Container* c2 = so_create_c(f2);

    Thread t1 = {.stack = c1};
    // c1 has no function yet
    if ((t1.stack != NULL) && (t1.stack->fp != NULL))
        ((Function*)t1.stack->fp)();
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "no function in Thread!\n");

    assign_f_to_c(f1, c1);
    // now c1 points to a function
    if ((t1.stack != NULL) && (t1.stack->fp != NULL))
        ((Function*)t1.stack->fp)();
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "no function in Thread!\n");

    // c2 points to f2...
    ((Function*)c2->fp)();

    t1.stack = c2;   // now t1 points to c2 that points to f2
    if ((t1.stack != NULL) && (t1.stack->fp != NULL))
        ((Function*)t1.stack->fp)();
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "no function in Thread!\n");

    so_delete_c(c1);
    so_delete_c(c2);
    return 0;
}

Container* so_create_c(Function* p)
{
    Container* container =
        (Container*)malloc(sizeof(Container));
    if (container == NULL) return NULL;
    container->fp = p;
    return container;
}

Container* so_delete_c(Container* c)
{
    if (c == NULL) return NULL;
    free(c);
    return NULL;
}

int assign_f_to_c(Function* pF, Container* c)
{
    if (pF == NULL) return -1;
    if (c == NULL) return -2;
    c->fp = pF;
    return 0;
}

void f1(void) { printf("hi from f1\n"); }
void f2(void) { printf("***** hi from f2! *****\n"); }

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78164360/call-a-function-inside-struct-but-struct-inside-a-void
```